# excel 2003 and excel 2007 row,column address difference

Tags: c#, excel-2007, excel-2003

in excel 2003 row,column addresses are specified like A,1 and C,12
but in excel 2007 this format changed to integers like 1,1 and 3,12

is there any built in support for converting old address to new one or is there any custom algorithm to convert these values.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what we use to convert Excel Column Letters to numbers and back

```
/// <summary>
/// 1 -> A<br/>
/// 2 -> B<br/>
/// 3 -> C<br/>
/// ...
/// </summary>
/// <param name="column"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ExcelColumnFromNumber(int column)
{
    string columnString = "";
    decimal columnNumber = column;
    while (columnNumber > 0)
    {
        decimal currentLetterNumber = (columnNumber - 1) % 26;
        char currentLetter = (char)(currentLetterNumber + 65);
        columnString = currentLetter + columnString;
        columnNumber = (columnNumber - (currentLetterNumber + 1)) / 26;
    }
    return columnString;
}

/// <summary>
/// A -> 1<br/>
/// B -> 2<br/>
/// C -> 3<br/>
/// ...
/// </summary>
/// <param name="column"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static int NumberFromExcelColumn(string column)
{
    int retVal = 0;
    string col = column.ToUpper();
    for (int iChar = col.Length - 1; iChar >= 0; iChar--)
    {
        char colPiece = col[iChar];
        int colNum = colPiece - 64;
        retVal = retVal + colNum * (int)Math.Pow(26, col.Length - (iChar + 1));
    }
    return retVal;
}
```